# DateTime Class not working in PHP / Apache

Tags: php, datetime, server

The DateTime class (as well as DatePeriod and DateInterval) seem to not work on my current server.  PHP 5.3.3 is installed per the phpinfo page, and when I run the get_declared_classes() function as an array to see what classes are defined, those classes do appear to exist:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass [1] => Exception [2] => ErrorException [3] =>
>   Closure [4] => DateTime [5] => DateTimeZone [6] => DateInterval [7] =>
>   DatePeriod [8] => LibXMLError...

However, even if I run the simplest of PHP code with DateTime, I will get an HTTP 500 error:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This older notation does work properly,

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But for some reason DateTime won't function.  I wrote some code using these DateTime objects on a different server and it worked fine.  Thoughts as to where I may have an error?  Is there a php.ini or other setting I should be considering?

-JF

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Try `echo ($date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));` instead, any better? How about `echo {$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")};`? Echo can sometimes do strange things with `$obj->function();` notation

Comment: @JonStory the code of the OP works perfectly (try it on phpfiddle.org) , it's because I ask what php version are using. In PHP >5.2 it's ok, in less maybe it's wrong

Comment: He states in the question that it's PHP 5.3.3, and therefore should be fine with this syntax

Comment: @PaulCrovella someone copy&paste your solution xD Kill him!

Comment: Thanks for everyon'es input -- Per @Paul Crovella's rec, the error.log provided useful info -- got an error message stating: _"It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function."_  Once I added that function to the php script, the objects worked fine.  Many thanks to the group!

Answer (score 7):

My best guess is you are using it in a class with namespace and thus DateTime needs an `\`
Please post a bit more code of your class so we can help you more.

So this is how it would work probably (mind the backslash `\`)

```
$date = new \DateTime('2000-01-01');
```

Also please post you error message for the 500. you'll probably find it in error.log of your server.

Comment: Awesome answer, solved issue in a minute, thanks dear :)

Comment: BTW i am using PHP Version 7.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem here...

It was the default time zone in php.ini, you can either use date_default_timezone_set() in your script or change it in the php.ini